# httpsCallable is not defined when using Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

For the past week I've been trying to setup Firebase Cloud Functions, but have been unable to import the dependencies needed.

This is in my script.js file, my main code:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
require("firebase/functions");

const testFunction = httpsCallable(functions, 'testFunction')
```

That returns this error:

```
script.js:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: httpsCallable is not defined
    at Object.parcelRequire.script.js.firebase/app (script.js:7)
    at newRequire (script.75da7f30.js:47)
    at script.75da7f30.js:81
    at script.75da7f30.js:120
```

In my index.html, I have this:

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.5/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.5/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.5/firebase-analytics.js"></script>


<script>  
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXX-XXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://XXXXX-XXXXX-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "XXXXX-XXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXX-XXXXX.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXX",
    appId: "1:XXXXXX:web:XXXXXX"
  };
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
        firebase.analytics()
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Edit: To upgrade to the new version of Firebase, I removed the script references in my html, did "npm i firebase@9.1.3" in my project folder, moved everything to my script.js file, and this is what it looks like now. But I still get the httpsCallable is not defined error, so the version didn't seem to affect it.

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import 'firebase/compat/functions'
import 'firebase/compat/auth'
import 'firebase/compat/analytics'
import 'firebase/compat/database'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXX-XXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://XXXXX-XXXXX-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "XXXXX-XXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXX-XXXXX.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXX",
    appId: "1:XXXXXX:web:XXXXXX"
  };
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
firebase.analytics()
```

Comment: You've imported v8 of the Firebase SDK, but are trying to use the syntax of v9 of the Firebase SDK. As this seems to be a new project, I recommend moving all code to v9, but using v9 means using JavaScript modules, which may cause some new headaches.

Comment: And the versions of all of your Firebase script includes should match exactly.  Right now, you are mixing at least two different versions.

Comment: @samthecodingman, thank you. This isn't a new project actually, it's almost finished, the last step was to add a referral system which I needed cloud functions to do. I edited my original post with the steps I took to upgrade to the new version, but that didn't change the original issue with httpsCallable not being defined.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for pointing that out. I upgraded to v9 of Firebase and removed those references entirely in favor of importing it with npm, but the original issue of httpsCallable not being defined hasn't been affected by upgrading.

Comment: @TheNomadicAspie have you tried the [samthecodingman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69638454/8753991)?

Answer (score 5):

When using the legacy namespaced syntax (<v8 & v9 compatibility-mode), use:

```js
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app" // just firebase/app in <v8
import 'firebase/compat/functions'         // just firebase/functions in <v8

const testFunction = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('testFunction')

testFunction({ /* data */ })
  .then((result) => { /* ... */ })
  .catch((err) => { /* ... */ })
```

For the modern modular syntax (v9+), use:

```js
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from 'firebase/functions'

const testFunction = httpsCallable(getFunctions(), 'testFunction')

testFunction({ /* data */ })
  .then((result) => { /* ... */ })
  .catch((err) => { /* ... */ })
```

These are [documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function).

Comment: Thanks @samthecoding man. I tried that syntax and no longer have the "is not defined" error, but now I'm getting this error:

"Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-mydomain-9d291.cloudfunctions.net/testFunction' from origin 'http://localhost:1234' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: @TheNomadicAspie If the function exists and is responsive, that CORS error wouldn't be thrown. When the function doesn't exist, Firebase doesn't set the CORS headers. Check your deployed functions and ensure that your `testFunction` has been properly deployed and exists with that name.

Comment: thank you for the info but it is deployed. When I run firebase deploy --only functions, it returns with "Deploy complete" and a checkmark. Is there anyway to check what's wrong specifically? I can't find a firebase-debug log file anywhere. I did find a database-debug.log and a ui-debug.log but neither had any errors or useful info.